# What actually happens when computer hangs

Tags: operating-systems, freeze, kernel

When we come to a point where computer hangs, what does actually happen inside of Windows's or Linux's kernel? Could a user space application be the cause that a whole os i frozen or could it just happen in kernel space? What is happening inside of Window's kernel when everything just freezes and you cannot click anything but just wait and look at the screen?

Is there any way of predicting that and could Windows ever have some kind of 'watchdog' mechanism that could snap it out of that situation and continue to work normally?